# TextBox DataObjectPastingEventHandler is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, events, textbox, paste

I'm trying make a MaskedTextBox, for avoid user paste value, I'm using `DataObjectPastingEventHandler` for process, but why that is not working?

```
    private void MaskPasteEvent(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you try this?

```
private void MaskPasteEvent(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    e.CancelCommand();
}
```

I'm basing this off of the MSDN remark [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobjectpastingeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (4th bullet point in the remarks section):

> Cancel the paste operation by calling CancelCommand.

Calling CancelCommand on the base class (DataObjectEventArgs) should set the CommandCancelled property to false on the derived DataObjectPastingEventsArgs.

Further links that may help:

- [DataObjectEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DataObjectEventArgs_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [DataObjectPastingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobjectpastingeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)